# jQuery img src change not immediate

Tags: jquery, image, src

I use jQuery in a simple image gallery. Images fadeOut, the src changes, and they fadeIn.

Frequently, the previous image is faded in; only once the element reaches full opacity is the new image displayed.

What could be causing the delay and subsequent jump to the new image?

HTML

```
<div id="slide">
    <img src="/img/products/image1.jpg">
</div>
```

JS

```
var index = 0;

$(function() {
    if (srcs.length > 1) {
        setInterval("slide(800, 800)", 6000);
    }
});

function slide(o,i) {
    index++;
    if (index == srcs.length) index = 0;
    $("#slide img").fadeOut(o, function() {
        $(this).attr("src", path + srcs[index] + ext);
        $(this).fadeIn(i);
    });
}
```

**Edit:** I put `fadeIn()` in `fadeOut()`'s callback, but now the problem occurs noticeably *every* time. The image fades out all the way, then fades all the way back in, *then* changes.

**Solution:** in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2435485/2231440), the `.each()` function caused a slight flicker during the new image's `fadeIn()`, but removing the `.each()` portion entirely fixed this.

Comment: This problem usually happens when you click to view the next or prev button 2 or more times in a row. If someone clicks the next button after only 400ms, then this problem could happen.

Comment: I've seen that elsewhere, but I don't have any buttons with it. It just fades out, changes, and fades in on a set interval.

Comment: probably just need a stop somewhere, http://api.jquery.com/stop/ give it a try and see if it helps

Comment: Can you suggest a place to put the stop?

Comment: try $("#slide img").stop(true, false).fadeOut(....) you can play around with the true/false

Comment: where and how do you populate the `srcs` array? - possibly post this code. what does the html inside `#slide` look like?

Comment: Oh yea didn't notice the fadeIn was not in the callback, see sareed's answer

Comment: HTML is posted. The images are all sourced correctly, they just don't show up immediately (My confusion is with the order of events in jQuery that causes this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding the fadeIn function as a callback function of fadeOut. That way you ensure the -out animation completes before the new image is loaded.

See documentation: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

```
$('#slide img').fadeOut(o, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    // Do fadeIn function here
});
```

Comment: I've done that, but now the problem happens every time a new picture loads. See edits

Comment: Take a look at this question/answer; you should be able to validate that the image is loaded first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435476/perform-function-in-attr-callback

Comment: Why is the `.each()` necessary in that answer? Can you clarify the comment in his code?

Currently, this works without the `.each()` (with it, there's a slight "flicker" during fadeIn)

Comment: I don't think it's necessary - in his case it was used to iterate through multiple objects. In your case, it's only one so you should be fine without. It was primarily the if(this.complete) that should help with the flicker/delayed appearance.

Answer (score 1):

It is because javascript does not wait for the fadeOut to complete before continuing through the code use something like this

```
    $('#slide img')
         .fadeOut(o, function(){
              $(this).attr('src', path + srcs[index] + ext);
              $('#slide img').fadeIn(i);
         });
```

and it should wait until the fadeOut is completed before starting the fadeIn.

Comment: Now the problem occurs every time the picture changes. See edit in OP

Comment: did you try $('#slide img').fadeIn(i) instead of .fadeIn(i)? if the code is just like the edit it may be a typo

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this on your preload function:

```
$.each(imgArray, function() {
    var i = new Image();
    i.src = path + this + ext;
});
```

Instead of ajax call, and also try this on your slide function:

```
$('#slide img').fadeOut(o, function(){
    var that = this;
    this.src = path + srcs[index] + ext;
    this.onload = function() {
        $(that).fadeIn(i);
    };
});
```

Comment: Doesn't your version of the preload do essentially the same thing?

Why store `this` in a temp? Also, won't `this` need to be `$(this)`?

Comment: I use the temp variable so dont lose the scope when using another wrapper, if you see well you have an anonymous function as the fadeOut callback, and inside that, another one, so there's a risk of changing the scope of "this" in the onload event callback. Also, is not $(this) because "onload" method, is not part of jQuery, its a javascript method. Then i use "$(that)" to extend the original "this" to jQuery methods, so "fadeIn" can be used. Let me know if you need me to explain with further details.

Comment: Oh and about the preload, yes its basicly the same, i just removed the jQuery wrapper and ajax calls.

Comment: Okay, those all made sense. Thanks for clarifying